# Blank Page after Reactjs project after creating firebase config

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to connect my project to the firebase firestore cloud in my project, I keep getting a blank white page after deploying it on `localhost:3000`, the header or other information is not showing up on my page at all. Here is the code for the config:

firebase.js:

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {
   apiKey: "APIKEYTHATIHAVEINMYPROJECT",
    authDomain: "tinder-clone-5f56c.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "tinder-clone-5f56c",
    storageBucket: "tinder-clone-5f56c.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "502714978016",
    appId: "1:502714978016:web:431f05b06d4019bf144a85",
    measurementId: "G-R6NDJ5FJ50"
};

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const database = firebaseApp.firestore();

export default database;
```

here is the js file the database should be connecting to:
TinderCards.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import database from './firebase';
import TinderCard from "react-tinder-card";
import './views/TinderCards.css';

function TinderCards() {
    const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        //this is where code runs...

        database.collection('people').onSnapshot(snapshot => (
           setPeople(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()))
        ))
    }, []);

    
    return ( 
        <div>
    <div className="tinderCards__cardContainer">
        {people.map((person) => (
            <TinderCard
                className="swipe"
                key={person.name}
                preventSwipe={["up", "down"]}
            >
                <div 
                style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${person.url})` }}
                className="card"
                >
                    <h3>{person.name}</h3>
                </div>
            </TinderCard>
            ))}
        </div>
    </div>
    );
}

export default TinderCards;
```

In the console, it tells me that

```
ERROR in ./src/firebase.js 14:21-41
export 'apps' (imported as 'firebase') was not found in 'firebase/app'
```

I'm not sure if I need to establish a 'const app' in order to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What version of firebase are you using? Try change your import from firebase/app to firebase/compat/app & firebase/firestore to firebase/compat/firestore

If you are using version 9

The following has change:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore';
```

to

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore';

const firebaseConfig = {//your configs};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const database = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

export{database}
```

You can checkout more here: https://modularfirebase.web.app/common-use-cases/firestore/